# Webap, Unable to read the entity body in Bufferless mode. The request stream has already been buffered

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to do a fileupload in the webapi and having issues.
The execution is getting failed at this line:

```
var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t => {..})
```

Hence I kept a code to see even if the content is rendered at the top of the above code as:

```
Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

Now the error says.

> "Unable to read the entity body in Bufferless mode. The request stream
>   has already been buffered."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have resolved this issue.
For some reason the framework wasn't liking the below code in WebAPIConfig.cs

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHostBufferPolicySelector), new WebHostBufferPolicySelector());
```

I have commented this line and my code started working. 
The only change I have seen is I have upgraded my .net framework to 4.6.1 and I think we no longer need this configuration for the newer frameworks.